Laravel passport slow query
Im using Laravel 10 (PHP 8.3) with MySQL database. The Laravel apps is deployed on server A, and the MySQL deployed in server B. For the first 3 weeks, the performance is awesome, but per today the Laravel is really slow.
After I investigate it on Sentry, I found weird query time for passport, because it's need 5 seconds to 20 seconds. The proof is in the picture.

If anyone have met this problem before, please enlighten me.
I've tried to disable Sentry, change database connection via VPC, change MySQL config, not fix it.

A few stats to check in mysql 1) How many rows in the oauth_access_tokens table. 2) Check if the table is properly indexed. 3) Check the overall size of the database. 4) number of queries being executed per second/minute

oauth_access_tokens has 2943 rows, and the table is properly indexed and its only 484KB.

If you have such a small table and it is indexed for this query, then not sure we can do much from a programming point of view. Database admins may be able to help to fine-tune mysql config for you, but you need to share lot more details with them about your current mysql config and other workloads that may be running on the same device.

Only 3K rows?  I suspect it is not SQL that is the slow down.  Provide SHOW CREATE TAB:LE and the SELECT`.
